# Drag and Drop Crystal Report output at run time?

Tags: crystal-reports, drag-and-drop, runtime

Is it possible to drag and drop the output of a crystal report (at run time) into a .NET Windows grid control (at run time)? 
My goal is to auto-populate the contents of a .NET windows grid control at run time from the output of a crystal report. 
I am aware of the export functionality of Crystal Reports but this functionality will not suffice as I am after a drag and drop solution.
Cheers
Jonathon

Comment: It might be possible, but wouldn't it be an option to use the original data that was used to generate the report as the dragged data source? That could be easier than trying to dig up the data from the report.

Comment: Hi Vesan. Thanks for the response. Unfortunately my application will not have access to the original data source. My intention is do build an application that can "import" the data (via Drag and Drop) from ANY application that produces a report on the screen (which was created by Crystal Reports).